# My (simple) javascript works in every browser but Firefox - Why?

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg

For universoty we had to "build" a xmas tree (svg) and use javascript to make the stars (ger stern(e)) rotate and the balls (ger (kugel(n)) change colors - one star had to be a shooting star. Everything work full points... but one penalty point as it doesn't work in Firefox
Does anyone has any idea why not?

The SVG is down below.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vi4lxgortgyeq3f/uebung4.svg

Thanks in advance... and please keep in mind it's my very first time to use javascript :D

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function farbe()
    {
    var a = "#ff0000";
    var b = "#007f00";

    if (document.getElementById("kugeln").style.fill == a)
     {
      document.getElementById("kugeln").style.setProperty('fill', b);
      }
      else
      {
      document.getElementById("kugeln").style.setProperty('fill', a);
      }
    }

 var initialTheta = 0; 
var thetaDelta = 0.3; 
var delay = 10; 

var stern; 
var timer;
```

```
function drehen()

{
  stern = document.getElementById("stern_1"); 
  stern.currentTheta = initialTheta; 
  timer = setInterval(Animation, delay);    

  stern_2 = document.getElementById("stern_2"); 
  stern_3 = document.getElementById("stern_3");
  stern_4 = document.getElementById("stern_4");

}



function stop()

{
  clearInterval(timer); 
  return; 
}



function Animation()

{ 
  stern.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + stern.currentTheta + " 50,50)"); 
  stern.currentTheta += thetaDelta;  

  stern_2.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + stern.currentTheta + " 50,50)");
  stern.currentTheta += thetaDelta;

  stern_3.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + stern.currentTheta + " 50,50)"); 
  stern.currentTheta += thetaDelta;   

  stern_4.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + stern.currentTheta + " 0,2000)"); 
  stern.currentTheta += thetaDelta;
}
```

Comment: How the hell should we know what the problem is by looking at an image of a christmas tree ?

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: I didn't want to post the full code - as i don't know which lines are important - i thought it might be the easiest to just open the svg with any editor just right click on it and see the source code...

Comment: create a fiddle of some sort that we can use then.

Answer (score 1):

The `drehen` function gets called two times in a row for each mouse over, so you are calling two times `setInterval` but recording only the last return value. You should call `clearInterval` before setting the new one.

Try something like

```
if(timer != undefined){
    clearInterval(timer);
}
timer = setInterval(Animation, delay);
```

Comment: So I copied the line of "clearInterval(timer)" (line 68) to function drehen() { - as a result the stars now stop spinning in Firefox - Whoohooo :D But the balls still can't change the color and I get something like small white lines over my xmas tree. It just looks strange but I think I could live with that.

Comment: @user3178550 I can't see any white line, could you make a screenshot pointing out how is it and how you want it to be? About the red balls: they doesn't change color because when you read the property `fill` you don't always get the exact string you specified, because the value is parsed and re-serialized by the browser. For example Firefox returns the color in the `rgb(255,0,0)` notation, but it's not a bug of Firefox. You should try something else, like applying and removing a class, instead of changing the inline style. However, if the answer has been useful, please up-vote it.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much - I'll try that tomorrow after work. May I ask whether that code of yours is meant for the function "drehen" or "stop" - It might be a dumb question but as this is my very first time with javascript I'm not exactly sure about what I'm doing there :D

Comment: Yesterday I finally managed to finish that task. It come down to the color code - instead of the hex code I just just "red" and "green" - done! I still see those white lines but as I have so many other things to to right now I have to live with that... I'm really thankful for all the help I got. Even though I didn't tried all of it. I'll keep it in mind for my next projects! Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing colours against hex values

```
var a = "#ff0000";
if (document.getElementById("kugeln").style.fill == a)
```

UAs don't have to return colours as hex values and in fact Firefox does not. It will convert your colour to an rgb or rgba representation. If you add an alert

```
alert(document.getElementById("kugeln").style.fill);
```

you'll see Firefox returns rgb(255, 0, 0) as the colour which is the same as #ff0000 expressed in a different way. So you could add a check for this kind of colour format or...

A more robust solution would be to have a visiblity:hidden element with the colour you want to compare to and then check against the fill property of that.

Comment: First of all - thank you. I'm not quite sure whether I get the very last part (in terms of: I haven't got a single clue) but I'll try to work it out tomorrow. :D

Comment: The visibility:hidden technique seems a bit kludgy to me.  It would be simpler just to have a global flag, such as `var ballsGreen = false` that you toggle between true and false.

Comment: Thanks a lot - as mentioned above I have some sort of solution - it might not be the prettiest and I'll try your ideas in future - but for now it has to stay the way it is ;-)